# Beautiful Soup remove blank lines and blank space

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, blank-line

I have tried looking for a solution on this site and the web and the google group for beautiful soup with no luck. I believe the problem is I am trying to run functions on empty data names. I just want to remove the blank lines and the empty space around the data coming out of the webpage. Thank you for any help.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
  help = 'Pull Data from RR web'

  def handle(self, *args, **options):
    page = requests.get('https://www.radioreference.com/apps/db/?sid=201&opt=all_tg#tgs')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    rr_name_list = soup.find(class_='titlebox')
    rr_name_list_items = rr_name_list.find_all('td')

    for rr_name in rr_name_list_items:
      names = rr_name.contents[0].strip()
      print "".join(line for line in names if not line.isspace()
      print(names)
```

Here is my Error:

```
NameError: name 'NavigableString' is not defined
print "".join(line for line in names if not line.isspace())
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: print need parenthesis , try `print (blah)`

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the first syntax error but now I get this which i think means there is no data coming out of names at some point.

       names = rr_name.contents[0].strip()
       TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable